# Сложносоставной союз "если... то"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Когда в сложноподчинённом предложении перед союзом "если... то" ставится запятая (или не ставится), и когда перед второй частью этого союза ставится запятая (или не ставится)? Речь идет о случаях типа "... что (,) если... (,) то..." и тому подобных. Если можно, объясните поподробнее, как тут с пунктуацией не ошибиться.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно смотреть туда, где оканчивается придаточное предложение: если там есть союз, то между этими двумя союзами запятая не ставится. Если нет союза, то запятая ставится.
Пример: "Он знал, что, когда она спит, её лучше не будить".

Answer (score 8):

Совершенно верно. Если условное придаточное с союзом "если" можно опустить или переставить в другое место без перестройки основного предложения, в которое вставлено данное придаточное, то запятая перед "если" ставится. Например: "Он почувствовал, что, если теперь он сядет, ему уже больше не подняться", но: "Он почувствовал, что если теперь он сядет, то ему уже больше не подняться".

Answer (score 3):

Перед "если" обычно стоит слово, соединяющее воедино конструкцию из двух частей предложения, соединенного союзом "если... то". Как правило, это "что" или "и". И поэтому после них и перед "если " запятая не ставится. Однако сам союз оказывается разделен запятой.
Например: *"...и если ты бросишь в автомат деньги, то получишь стакан кофе"*.

Comment: Значит, если у союза не будет второй части "то", то запятую перед "если" надо будет ставить?