# Почему слова "мертвец", "покойник", "утопленник" одушевленные?

Tags: лингвистика

Наткнулся на такое правило: 
[image]

Мне помнится, тут уже обсуждалось нечто подобное, но хотелось бы знать, почему так? Какой логикой тут можно руководствоваться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы про то, почему покойник, мертвец и утопленник относятся к одушевлённым? Какой логикой руководствоваться? Никакой. Разве что внутренней логикой языка.
Ну или логикой наших далёких предков, посчитавших мертвецов одушевлёнными.

Answer (score 7):

Нашла интересную статью:   http://rus.1september.ru/articlef.php?ID=200204103.

В ней этим словам есть следующее объяснение: "Почему существительные мертвец и покойник одушевленные?

Осмысление человеком живой природы неразрывно связано с понятием смерти. ‘Умерший’ – это всегда ‘бывший живым’, ранее обладавший жизнью. Кроме того, фольклор не случайно изобилует историями о живых мертвецах. До сих пор можно встретить отголоски представлений наших далеких предков о том, что мертвым присуща некая особая форма жизни, будто мертвый человек способен слышать, думать, вспоминать.

Существительные мертвец, покойник, усопший и др. обозначают умерших людей, т.е. обладают признаком ‘человек’ – самым важным для значения одушевленности. А вот слово труп означает ‘тело умершего организма’, т.е. только материальную оболочку (ср. выражения трупы убитых, трупы умерших). Видимо, это семантическое различие объясняет грамматическую одушевленность названий умерших и неодушевленность слова труп: Как крепки камни все в призваниях своих, – Когда покойников накрывши стерегут (К. Случевский); А созову я тех, на которых работаю, мертвецов православных... – Перекрестись! Созывать мертвых на новоселье (А. Пушкин); Настёне только однажды, еще задолго до войны, пришлось видеть утопленника (В. Распутин); Возчики бросают трупы на сани с деревянным стуком (А. Солженицын)."

Там и про другие слова есть информация. Я помню с институтских времен, что кукла, матрешка и т. п. — тоже одушевленные. Вирус, микроб, робот — в зависимости от контекста могут быть одушевленными или неодушевленными.  "Нечисть" сказочная тоже одушевленная.

Comment: *обладают признаком ‘человек* - интересное наблюдение, но, как  это часто бывает у филологов-любителей, причина и следствие, видимо, перепутаны. Скорее всего обратное - мы (или предки наши) наделяем одушевленностью объекты, которые грамматически таковой обладают. Что для науки, наверное, куда более важно, но ответом на конкретный вопрос служить не может.

Answer (score 2):

*Мертвец, покойник, утопленник* -- одушевленные с точки зрения грамматики. Если ставим вопрос, то "кто?", а не "что?". А также форма винительного падежа данных существительных образовывается именно как у одушевленных существительных:
Винительный п. Мертвеца (кого?, а не что?)

Comment: Это признак, а не причина.

Comment: Хорошо, если отдалиться от грамматики, может, такое явление существует из-за того, что неудобно человека, некогда живого, называть "что", а не "кто". То есть из уважения...

Answer (score 2):

Вообще понятие одушевлённости очень тонкое. Здесь речь идёт не о физиологии, а о языковом явлении, о грамматике русского языка. Ведь если разобраться - жареный гусь тоже уже неживой, но остаётся быть "кто?" А любое растение живёт, дышит, питается, даже хищники есть среди них, только что не ходит, а всё равно "что?". А в казахском языке вообще на вопрос кто?(кім?)отвечают только слова, каким-либо образом относящиеся к человеку, а все остальные: кошка, собака, лошадь, корова и т.д.- отвечают на вопрос не? (что?).

Answer (score 2):

Cлово "труп" в винительном падеже имеет нулевое окончание, как и все неодушевленные предметы мужского рода (вижу стол, стул, шкаф).

Одушевленные предметы мужского рода имеют ненулевое окончание. Поскольку "покойник", "мертвец" и "утопленник" имеют ненулевое окончание в винительном падеже (вижу покойника, мертвеца, утопленника), то и относиться они будут к одушевленным существительным.

Comment: Трупов здесь только не хватало. Хотелось бы видеть ответы на вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы узнать, одушевлённое или неодушевлённое, нужно просклонять слово во множественном числе по трём падежам: именительный, родительный и винительный.

И. п. мертвецы

Р. п. мертвецов

В. п. мертвецов

Если родительный и винительный падеж совпадают, то слово одушевлённое, а если совпадают именительный и винительный, то неодушевлённое.

Comment: Про ЕСЛИ, ТО: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/341/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE. А вот о пробелах и их роли не стоит, наверное, говорить.

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения строения и особенностей языка, а не человеческих представлениях о жизнеспособности предметов, в винительном падеже ОДУШЕВЛЕННОЕ существительное меняет окончание, НЕОДУШЕВЛЕННОЕ совпадает с именительным падежом.

Сравнение:

- дерево (и.в) - дерево (в.п);
- покойник (и.п) - покойника (в.п);
- человек (и.п) - человека (в.п);

Надеюсь, доступно объяснила.

Comment: У одушевлённых существительных второго (по-школьному) склонения форма винительного падежа совпадает с формой родительного, а у неодушевлённых - с формой именительного. Вот так правильнее, по-моему.

Comment: darikorzh, я не вчитывался, насколько доступно, но вы явно перепутали причину и следствие.
Вопрос в том, почему эти три слово оказались грамматически одушевлёнными, а не то, как они изменяются по падежам.

Answer (score 1):

Очень хорошо ответил на этот вопрос писатель Юрий Поляков в одном из своих произведений. Там герой повести, учитель русского языка, объясняет детям так: "Покойник, мертвец, утопленник - это мёртвые личности, а труп - мёртвое тело". По-моему, прекрасно объяснил.

Answer (score 0):

Какой логикой руководствоваться? Просто каждый из них человек, только мёртвый. Хотя труп - уже неодушевлённое существительное. Язык вообще вещь во многом нелогичная.

Comment: Труп может быть не только человеческий, а вот мертвец, покойник и утопленник -- это явно про человека.

Answer (score -1):

Правило такое:для того, чтобы узнать одушевленное или нет, нужно слово во множественном числе поставить в винительный падеж... если винительный падеж совпадает с родительным, то предмет одушевленный, если с именительным, то - неодушевленный. Винить кого/что - мертвецов (совпадает с родительным, поэтому одушевленный)... винить кого/что - трупы (совпадает с именительным, поэтому неодушевленный)...

Comment: Вопрос не в том, как проверить, а в том "почему" так случилось..